# I get Cannot use import statement outside a module error while unit testing with Jest in quasar

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, quasar-framework, ts-jest

I want to test my quasar application with jest, when i run the test i get error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  58 | </template>
  59 | <script>
> 60 | import { QCalendarDay, today } from '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/index.js'
     | ^
  61 | import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarVariables.sass'
  62 | import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarTransitions.sass'
  63 | import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarDay.sass'
```

root/src/components/calendars/daily-calendar

```
div(style="display: flex")
  q-calendar-day.rounded-borders(ref="dailyCalendar" :locale="localeLanguage" :hour24-format="true" :interval-minutes="appointmentDuration" v-model="selectedDate" view="day" animated bordered transition-next="slide-left" transition-prev="slide-right" no-active-date :interval-start="24" :interval-count="68" :interval-height="28")
    template(#head-day-event="{ scope: { timestamp } }")
      div(style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 2px")
        template(v-for="event in modelValueProxy[timestamp.date]" :key="event.id")
          q-badge(v-if="!event.time" :class="badgeClasses(event, 'header')" :style="badgeStyles(event, 'header')" style="width: 100%; cursor: pointer; height: 12px; font-size: 10px; margin: 1px")
            .title.q-calendar__ellipsis
              | {{ event.title }}
```

daily calendar script

```
    import { QCalendarDay, today } from '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/index.js'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarVariables.sass'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarTransitions.sass'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarDay.sass'
import lookie from 'lookie'
import moment from 'moment'
import { date } from 'quasar'

import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'WeekSlotDayBody',
  components: {
    QCalendarDay
  },
```

root/test/jest/**tests**/dailyCalendar.spec.ts

````
import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals'
import { installQuasarPlugin } from '@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import dailyCalendar from '@/components/calendars/daily-calendar.vue'

/*
 * You can provide a config object as param like such:
 *
 * ```ts
 * installQuasarPlugin({ plugins: { Dialog } });
 * ```
 */
installQuasarPlugin()

describe('dailyCalendar', () => {
  it('mounts without errors', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(dailyCalendar)

    expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
````

jest.config.js

```
    const esModules = ['quasar', 'quasar/lang', 'lodash-es'].join('|')

/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
    // TODO: Remove if resolved natively
    // See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/175
    'vue-jest': {
      pug: { doctype: 'html' }
    },
    // Remove if using `const enums`
    // See https://huafu.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/isolatedModules#example
    'ts-jest': {
      isolatedModules: true
    }
  },
  roots: ['<rootDir>/../'],
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/../'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  // Jest assumes we are testing in node environment, specify jsdom environment instead
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  // noStackTrace: true,
  // bail: true,
  // cache: false,
  // verbose: true,
  // watch: true,
  collectCoverage: false,
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/test/jest/coverage',
  coverageReporters: ['json-summary'],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.js',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.jsx',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.tsx'
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '.d.ts$'],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      //  branches: 50,
      //  functions: 50,
      //  lines: 50,
      //  statements: 50
    }
  },
  testMatch: [
    // Matches tests in any subfolder of 'src' or into 'test/jest/__tests__'
    // Matches all files with extension 'js', 'jsx', 'ts' and 'tsx'
    '<rootDir>/test/jest/__tests__/**/*.(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.jest.(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'
  ],
  // Extension-less imports of components are resolved to .ts files by TS,
  //  grating correct type-checking in test files.
  // Being 'vue' the first moduleFileExtension option, the very same imports
  //  will be resolved to .vue files by Jest, if both .vue and .ts files are
  //  in the same folder.
  // This guarantee a great dev experience both for testing and type-checking.
  // See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/188#issuecomment-620750728
  moduleFileExtensions: ['vue', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^quasar$': 'quasar/dist/quasar.esm.prod.js',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
    '^layouts/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/layouts/$1',
    '^pages/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/pages/$1',
    '^assets/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets/$1',
    '^boot/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/boot/$1',
    '.*css$': '@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest/stub.css'
  },
  transform: {
    // See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string
    [`^(${esModules}).+\\.js$`]: 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest',
    // vue-jest uses find-babel-file, which searches by this order:
    //  (async) .babelrc, .babelrc.js, package.json, babel.config.js
    //  (sync) .babelrc, .babelrc.js, babel.config.js, package.json
    // https://github.com/tleunen/find-babel-config/issues/33
    '.*\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!(${esModules}))`],
  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue']
}
```

Error

```
Cannot find module '@/components/calendars/daily-calendar.vue' from 'test/jest/__tests__/MyButton.spec.ts'
```

package.json

```
    {

  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "quasar dev",
    "build": "quasar build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.vue ./",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,ts,vue,scss,html,md,json}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "test": "echo \"See package.json => scripts for available tests.\" && exit 0",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn && yarn build",
    "make-badges": "istanbul-badges-readme",
    "test:unit:ui": "majestic",
    "test:unit": "jest --updateSnapshot",
    "test:unit:ci": "jest --ci",
    "test:unit:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:unit:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:unit:watchAll": "jest --watchAll",
    "serve:test:coverage": "quasar serve test/jest/coverage/lcov-report/ --port 8788",
    "concurrently:dev:jest": "concurrently \"quasar dev\" \"jest --watch\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
    "@quasar/cli": "^1.3.2",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.13.6",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.6",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.22.3",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "echarts": "^5.3.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "froala-editor": "^4.0.11",
    "happy-dom": "^6.0.4",
    "include-media": "^1.4.10",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "lookie": "^1.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "moment-business-days": "^1.2.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "quasar": "^2.7.5",
    "reactive-state": "^3.7.2",
    "sass": "^1.52.1",
    "serve-static": "^1.15.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "ui": "^0.2.4",
    "vitest": "^0.18.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.33",
    "vue-echarts": "^6.0.2",
    "vue-froala-wysiwyg": "^4.0.11",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.0-beta.36",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-alpha.10",
    "vue-moment-tz": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.14",
    "yarn": "^1.22.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prettier/plugin-pug": "^2.0.0",
    "@quasar/app-webpack": "^3.5.3",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-qcalendar": "^4.0.0-beta.15",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing": "^2.0.4",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest": "^3.0.0-alpha.10",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.29",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.21.0",
    "eslint": "^8.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^25.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "istanbul-badges-readme": "^1.8.2",
    "majestic": "^1.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.5.3"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "stream": false
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 Chrome versions",
    "last 10 Firefox versions",
    "last 4 Edge versions",
    "last 7 Safari versions",
    "last 8 Android versions",
    "last 8 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 8 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 10 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Opera versions"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.22.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@types/eslint": "8.4.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/eslint": "8.4.3"
  }
}
```

When I run the above gesture conf, I get module not found error. this config is actually the config that comes when loading jest with quasar. I don't understand why I am getting such an error.

Comment: Please open a new question for the new error.

Answer (score -1):

Remove nonexistent `/calendars` folder from your import path:

```
import dailyCalendar from '@/components/calendars/daily-calendar.vue'
```

Should be updated to:

```
import dailyCalendar from '@/components/daily-calendar.vue'
```

---

The import is looking for a file path that doesn't exist, given that the actual file is at `root/src/components/daily-calendar` and `@/` is mapped to `root/src`. If the actual file path was `root/src/components/calendars/daily-calendar`, the import would work.

Comment: I edited it to be @/components/calendars/daily-calendar.vue but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you move the file location or remove calendars from the import path (even though above edit still has it)? Did you update all tests with that import path?

Comment: I solved the problem by replacing @ with ../../, but this time I also get an 
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      58 | </template>
      59 | <script>
    > 60 | import { QCalendarDay, today } from '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/index.js' error.

Comment: Hmm but your edit of the question suggests you also moved the file itself? Is the error the exact same?